# What is the quickest way to perfect global warming?

Tags: atmosphere, weather, climate-change

The second terrestrial planet orbiting the Sun is shrouded in greenhouse gases, the entire surface of Venus is always scorching hot due to the high concentration of atmospheric carbon dioxide which traps heat from escaping. Okay the science lesson ends here.

I got a visit from the goddess of love and maybe sex, she requested we make our own atmosphere to resemble Venus's in the shortest possible time. I already told her how faithful we all are and showed her our progress but she ain't impressed.

How can I, as the president of US, together with my god-brothers, president of PRC as well as PM of England (assuming like minds attract) be able to meet the goddess' expectations without delay? The solution with a result closely matching the conditions of Venus's atmosphere wins.

Also don't upset her she would simply banish all the dead from the underworld to the world of the living! Trust me she's got connections and ties and you may not touch the Illuminati.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Revoke every [CFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorofluorocarbon) regulation law

Hurray! Now every appliance(some) and spray cans would release CFCs. It would be an excellent way to destroy all that pesky ozone in our atmosphere that blocking the sun's rays!

## Revoke every environmental conservation law

Excellent! Now we can allow our [Greenhouse gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas) emissions to run rampant! It will help us stay warm and toasty when the winter comes(if it comes) and let those factories save money from needing to buy those bothersome environmental measures.

## Burn down every forest and plant life

Yay! Fires keep us warm! It also gives out carbon dioxide, carbon monoxide and some other gases depending on what's cooking. All of which are usually [Greenhouse gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_gas).

## A lot of cow farts and [Landfill gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landfill_gas)

Methane which is a greenhouse gas is much better at doing its job than carbon dioxide.

Comment: You're getting two environmental problems confused. Ozone is a major greenhouse gas. In fact, the zero ODP HFCs that we use now have a higher GWP than the CFCs they replaced, precisely because they don't come apart when UV light hits them.

Answer (score 0):

**Is temporary result sufficient?**
Basicly environment of Venus is kept best by the position of the planet. 
Eart can be easily transformed to have a Venus-like athmosphere, but keeping it up would take also huge effort. If temporary solution is OK, then I'm with Skye's 1st and 3rd idea combined: burn down all green materia, it will contribute to break down ozone layer, which will expose surface to heavyweight UV radiation.

However, Earth will - in millenias or slower - return to normal due to it's position in the star system. So should the human race extint in the succesful task to turn the planet into a constant 462 °C surface temperature, 9.3 megapascal (Earth is 101kPa) pressurized planet, if the terraforming effort will seize at some point, the planet will turn back to "normal".

**What is the goal of the goddess with this request?**

Answer (score 0):

#### Freeze Earth's core!

Now there's some radiation hitting us and the atmosphere is stripped away as our ozone is depleted ('cuz of the new anti-environmental laws pouring CFC's into the air) even more rapidly. Ouch! Our oceans evaporate slowly as the air we breath is stripped away into space.

#### Magnesium!!

I'm going to shamelessly quote this wicked answer by LSerni, answering [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74586/removing-an-atmosphere-from-a-previously-habitable-world/74599#74599)

> [The]first [magnesium] pellets would burn violently in oxygen, forming magnesium oxide powder and raising the atmosphere's temperature enough to allow further reaction of magnesium with nitrogen (actually this wouldn't even be needed - the reentry heat would suffice to that). The resulting magnesium nitride is solid, but it would quickly react with water vapour from the now boiling surface of the oceans to form magnesium hydroxyde and ammonia, which would mostly dissolve in the remaining water while the dissolved oxygen would get outgassed (completely depleting the oceanic oxygen would take a long time). A large part of the available oxygen would be consumed by the fires engulfing the planet, though - forests, cities, all kinds of organic matter.

Which, of course, releases lots of CO2 (which makes up lots of Venus's atmosphere) which further degrades the atmosphere.

#### And then . . .

Just up production of CFC's and you're there! Although you're dead, at least you weren't killed by the wicked goddess!

> May add more info as I think of other random stuff

Careful: You can't survive here or on Venus simply because of the atmosphere. (Besides the heat.)